# How to generated the below XMlStructure Based on list size?

Tags: apex, xml

How to generated the below XMl Based on list size?

Hi,

the below list has 3 records. I need to generate the below XML Structure Based on list size.

```
List<Product_for_Sample_Literature__c>  ProductLineItems =[SELECT id,Sample_Literature_Request__c,Batch_Information__c,Detail__c,Product__r.Name,Quantity__c,Product_APN__c  from Product_for_Sample_Literature__c WHERE Sample_Literature_Request__c ='a0Eb0000001UVLF'];
```

If list size has one, the XMl should like this.And assign the values of list to below elements

```
<Items>
            <SFDCLineID>1</SFDCLineID>
            <Material>ProductLineItems.Batch_Information__c</Material>
            <Quantity>ProductLineItemsQuantity__c</Quantity>

</Items>
```

If list size has two, the XMl should like this.

```
<Items>
            <SFDCLineID>1</SFDCLineID>
            <Material>ProductLineItems.Batch_Information__c</Material>
            <Quantity>ProductLineItemsQuantity__c</Quantity>

</Items>

<Items>
            <SFDCLineID>2</SFDCLineID>
            <Material>ProductLineItems.Batch_Information__c</Material>
            <Quantity>ProductLineItemsQuantity__c</Quantity>

</Items>
```

the list size has 3 ,

```
<Items>
            <SFDCLineID>1</SFDCLineID>
            <Material>ProductLineItems.Batch_Information__c</Material>
            <Quantity>ProductLineItemsQuantity__c</Quantity>

</Items>

<Items>
            <SFDCLineID>2</SFDCLineID>
            <Material>ProductLineItems.Batch_Information__c</Material>
            <Quantity>ProductLineItemsQuantity__c</Quantity>

</Items>

<Items>
            <SFDCLineID>3</SFDCLineID>
            <Material>ProductLineItems.Batch_Information__c</Material>
            <Quantity>ProductLineItemsQuantity__c</Quantity>

</Items>
```

etc, how i can acheive this ?can anyone help me on this

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you have an idea how to achieve it? Are you blocked with something? Or do you want community to write your code instead you? :)

Comment: i don't have any idea how  to achieve this.

Comment: no worries ! there is a nice [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm) that will help you to understand how you can do it with apex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

Apex provides classes that enable you to work with XML content using the DOM (Document Object Model).

Execute below code in anonymous window,

```
List<Product_for_Sample_Literature__c>  ProductLineItems =[SELECT id,Sample_Literature_Request__c,Batch_Information__c,Detail__c,Product__r.Name,Quantity__c,Product_APN__c  from Product_for_Sample_Literature__c WHERE Sample_Literature_Request__c ='a0Eb0000001UVLF'];

    Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();    
    Dom.Xmlnode rootNode = doc.createRootElement('ProductLineItems', null, null);        
    Integer SFDCLineID=0;

    for (Product_for_Sample_Literature__c Product: ProductLineItems ) {
        Dom.Xmlnode ProductNode = rootNode.addChildElement('Items', null, null);
        ProductNode.addChildElement('SFDCLineID', null, null).addTextNode(++SFDCLineID);
        ProductNode.addChildElement('Material', null, null).addTextNode(Product.Batch_Information__c);
        ProductNode.addChildElement('Quantity', null, null).addTextNode(Product.Quantity__c);

    }        
    system.debug(doc.toXmlString());
```

Resulting log, you will be getting the XML String like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductLineItems>
<Items>
            <SFDCLineID>1</SFDCLineID>
            <Material>Product 1</Material>
            <Quantity>3</Quantity>

</Items>
<Items>
            <SFDCLineID>2</SFDCLineID>
            <Material>Product 2</Material>
            <Quantity>4</Quantity>

</Items>
</ProductLineItems>
```

Comment: System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null

Comment: I am getting the above error when i am trying to execute the above code in anonymous window,

Comment: Value your receiving from  "Product_for_Sample_Literature__c" object , Has null  values, because of that your getting error.

Comment: @Spyder Below code is tested with account, as i dont have your object in my org. Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();    
Dom.Xmlnode rootNode = doc.createRootElement('ProductLineItems', null, null);
list<account> accountList = [select  id, name from  Account limit 10 ];
for (Account eachAccount : accountList) {
    Dom.Xmlnode accountNode = rootNode.addChildElement('Account', null, null);
    accountNode.addChildElement('id', null, null).addTextNode(eachAccount.id);
    accountNode.addChildElement('Name', null, null).addTextNode(eachAccount.Name);
}
system.debug(doc.toXmlString());

Comment: Its working Nitesh

Comment: @Spyder Your welcome...

Answer (score 0):

You can generate XML using the classes in the `Dom` namespace, but there's an easier way (well, easier for me at least).

You can use Visualforce to generate XML.

```
<!-- 
    You'll probably need to create a small controller extension.
    showHeader, standardStyleSheets, sidebar, applyBodyTag, and applyHtmlTag are all set
      to false to prevent the HTML that Salesforce usually generates automatically
      from appearing in the XML

-->
<apex:page standardController="Product_for_Sample_Literature__c" extensions="MyExtension" showHeader="false" standardStyleSheets="false" sidebar="false" contentType="text/xml" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" cache="false">
<!-- I think there's an issue with printing the xml header tag, so we'll need to take care
  of that elsewhere -->
<apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="lineItem">
    <!-- 
    There's no problem using non-visualforce, non-html tags here.
    We don't need to do anything special to make up our own tags (XML is just a bunch of
      arbitrarily defined tags, after all).
    With the contentType being text/xml, your browser won't try to render these
      tags as HTML.
    -->
    <Items>
        <!-- There's no standard way to get the current index number of an apex:repeat.
        There are a few different ways you could achieve this, but I'll leave that 
          for you to figure out.
        -->
        <material>{!lineItem.Batch_Information__c}</material>
        <quantity><!-- the code/merge syntax statement in here will be similar to the one above --></quantity>
    </Items>
</apex:repeat>
```

The extension class you would need is really straightforward.

```
public class MyExtension{
    // Variable to hold the records that we need to query
    List<Product_For_Sample_Literature__c> records{get;set;}

    // The same, basic constructor signature for a controller extension
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        // Just like if this were for a regular visualforce page, you'll need to query
        //   for all the fields that you'll be using
        // We need to use ApexPages.currentPage() to get the page parameters that you
        //   pass in.
        records = [SELECT Id, Batch_Information__c, Quantity__c FROM Product_For_Sample_Literature__c WHERE Sample_Literature_Request = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('reqNum')];
    }
}
```

Using these to generate XML in Apex is also pretty simple.

```
PageReference myXMLGenerator = Page.MyVisualforcePage;
myXMLGenerator.getParameters.put('reqNum', 'a0Eb0000001UVLF');
String xmlResult;

if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
    // As of API v34.0, pageReference.getContent() is considered a callout.
    // That means that we can't run this code in a unit test, which is the primary
    //   drawback to this approach.
    xmlResult = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\n' + myXMLGenerator.getContent().toString());
}
```

For very short and simple XML structures, like the one in your example, this approach probably involves more code/typing than just using the classes in the `Dom` namespace. However, for more complicated XML (especially if you have a few levels of nested tags), this approach stands head and shoulders above trying to generate XML with Apex alone.

The other benefit to this approach is that, being a visualforce page, it's pretty simple to just open a tab in your browser, navigate to `/apexPages/MyVisualforcePage?reqNum="a0Eb0000001UVLF"`, and look at the resulting XML to verify that the XML looks correct (no need for anonymous apex and debug statements).